# Fortran Polymorphism (field overloading?)

Tags: inheritance, fortran, polymorphism

Using Visual Studio 2015 and Intel Visual Fortran 2017.

I'm not sure if this is a thing you can do in Fortran or any language really, but it seems like it could be very useful in reducing boiler plate code in my project if there is an option for doing this or something similar. I'm aware I might just not know what to be searching for.

The way I am currently doing it:

```
Module Example

Type SpecificType_T
    real :: x
End Type SpecificType_T

Type, abstract :: List_A
     class(*) :: obj
contains
    procedure :: getObj => list_getSpecificType
End Type List_A

Type SpecificTypeCollection_T
contains
    procedure :: getSpecificType => collection_getSpecificType
End Type SpecificTypeCollection_T

contains

subroutine list_getObj(this, obj)

    class(List_A), intent(inout) :: this
    class(*), intent(out) :: obj

    allocate(obj, source=this%obj)

end subroutine list_getObj

function container_getSpecificType(this) result(st)

    class(SpecificTypeCollection_T), intent(in) :: this

    type(SpecificType_T) :: st

    class(*), allocatable :: obj

    select type(obj)
    type is(SpecificType_T)
        st = obj
    end select

end function container_getSpecificType
End Module Example

Program test
    use Example
    type(SpecificType_T) :: a
    type(SpecificTypeCollection_T) :: stc
    a = stc%getSpecificType()
end Program test
```

The below is an example of what I am wanting to do (even though I am aware this is not valid fortran). Basically I just want to avoid having to wrap every abstract type's function with boiler plate for every inherited type.

```
Module Example
Type SpecificType_T
    real :: x
End Type SpecificType_T

Type, abstract :: List_A
     class(*) :: obj
contains
    procedure :: getObj => list_getSpecificType
End Type List_A

Type SpecificTypeCollection_T
    class(SpecificType_T) :: obj
End Type SpecificTypeCollection_T

function list_getObj(this) result(obj)

    class(List_A), intent(inout) :: this
    class(*), intent(out) :: obj

    allocate(obj, source=this%obj)

end function list_getObj
End Module Example

Program test
    use Example
    type(SpecificType_T) :: a
    type(SpecificTypeCollection_T) :: stc
    a = stc%getObj()
end Program test
```

EDIT (for clarification): Basically it seems like it would be really convenient if I could create some abstract base object with procedures like `push` or `pop` that act on the unlimited polymorphic field also in the abstract object, and then have an inherited type that can enforce a specific derived type without needing to create wrappers in the inherited object for all of the procedures modifying the unlimited polymorphic object.

Is this a thing that can be done in Fortran, or is there another viable alternative I'm not aware of?

Comment: I am aware of deferred bindings for procedures. I guess what I'm looking for is deferred bindings for a class field of a derived type. I haven't been able to find it, but many times previously I just haven't known the word to search for.

Comment: Good. I'm working on an example, but my actual code that I want to use is a lot and I can't transfer data from it to the one connected to internet. So it might be a while.

Comment: Some programmers do release libraries exemplifying generic programming in Fortran. You can have a look at http://fortran-foss-programmers.github.io/FIAT/ for instance to see how to implement abstract data types.